# Clang-format align multiple function parameters

Tags: c++, clang-format

I would like to configure clang-format to do this :

from

```
void test1 (int p);
void long_name (int p);
```

to

```
void test1     (int p);
void long_name (int p);
```

Comment: Have you tried `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations`?

Comment: Yes it's not working for function parameters

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think clang-format supports this, at least as of version 10.0

Answer (score 0):

To do that, I use another extension - codealignment. I select all lines that contain function declarations. Do "F1" and search align by string and put (enter). It is related to [format function declaration Clang-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417895/format-function-declaration-clang-format).